# Relation between variance, standard deviation and mean

Tags: probability-distributions, variance, exponential-distribution

I have a survival function with multiple terms like:

$$ S(X) = {1 \over 3}e^{(-x/3)}+{2 \over 3}e^{(-x/6)}$$

I want to calculate the expected value and variance.

$$ E(X) = \int_0^{\infty} S(X) = 5 $$

For the variance I used:

$$ S(X) = 1 - F(X) = 1 - ({1 \over 3}e^{(-x/3)}+{2 \over 3}e^{(-x/6)})  $$

$$ f(x) = {1 \over 9 } e^{-x/3} + {2 \over 18 } e^{-x/6} $$

$$ \sigma^2 = 2 \int_0^{\infty} xS(X) dx - E(X)^2 = \int_0^{\infty} x^2f(x)dx -E(X)^2  = 54 - 25 = 29$$

For exponential distributions, the mean is $ 1 \over \lambda$ and the variance $1 \over \lambda^2 $, so that the $ E(X) = \sqrt{\sigma^2} = \sigma$. This is not the case for the formula above and somehow I think I understood the whole thing not completely.

The first question is, is my variance correct? If yes, how can I imagine it visually? I always thought about it as from 0 to $\sigma^2$ with the mean in the middle.

Thank you, WiPu

Comment: Should $\frac{2}{6}$ be $\frac{2}{3}$? It seems you are treating $X$ as a nonnegative random variable, but $S(0) \ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, thank you this was a typo.

Comment: You seem to be assuming $E[X^2] = 2 \int_0^\infty S(x) \, dx$ but this doesn't lead to $54$. Is there a typo?

Comment: Yes, there was one. I corrected the expressions. Thank you for spotting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem concerns a random sampling of *one of two* exponential distributions. So$$\Bbb EX=\tfrac133+\tfrac236=5,\,\Bbb EX^2=\frac132\cdot3^2+\frac232\cdot6^2=54,$$as per your calculations. More generally, if $X$ samples $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_i)$ with probability $p_i$ then$$\Bbb EX=\sum_i\frac{p_i}{\lambda_i},\,\Bbb EX^2=\sum_i\frac{2p_i}{\lambda_i^2}=\sum_{ij}\frac{2p_ip_j}{\lambda_i^2}\implies\sigma^2=\sum_{ij}\left(\frac{2p_ip_j}{\lambda_i^2}-\frac{p_ip_j}{\lambda_i\lambda_j}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why can the standard deviation ($\sigma$) be higher than the mean, if I have a combined distribution? When I calculate the deviation for each of the distributions I get $\sigma_1 = 3$ and $\sigma_2 = 6$. This is then again 1/3*(3)+2/3*6 = 5 which is the same as the mean. I really struggle to understand this.

Comment: @WiPU As the above calculation shows, it's due to the sampled distributions having different values of $\lambda$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the follow-up!